# GeckoEngine and C# load dll drivers problem

Tags: c#

```
Message: Couldn't load library  C:\_ZAGON\TMP\DLL\GeckoEngine\xulRunner\freebl3.dll
There was an error during dll loading :  C:\_ZAGON\TMP\DLL\GeckoEngine\xulRunner\freebl3.dll, error - 18
Stack trace:    at TMP.CrawlerApp.CrawlerApp.LoadWin32Library(String dllFilePath) in CrawlerApp.cs:line 149
```

line 149:

```
throw new Exception(String.Format("Couldn't load library {0}{1}{2}", dllFilePath, Environment.NewLine, exc.Message), exc);
```

whole code:

```
DllImport("wininet")]
        private static extern int InternetGetConnectedState(ref int lpdwFlags, int dwReserved);

        [DllImport("wininet")]
        private static extern int InternetAutodial(int dwFlags, int hwndParent);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string dllFilePath, IntPtr hFile, uint dwFlags);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr dllPointer);

        private IntPtr LoadWin32Library(string dllFilePath)
        {
            try
            {
                IntPtr moduleHandle = LoadLibraryEx(dllFilePath, IntPtr.Zero, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH);
                if (moduleHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    // I'm gettin last dll error
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new ApplicationException(
                        string.Format("There was an error during dll loading : {0}, error - {1}", dllFilePath, errorCode)
                        );
                }

                return moduleHandle;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format("Couldn't load library {0}{1}{2}", dllFilePath, Environment.NewLine, exc.Message), exc);
            }
        }

private void LoadDLL()
        {
            string XulRunnerPath = @" C:\_ZAGON\TMP\DLL\GeckoEngine\xulRunner";\NCrawler\GeckoEngine\xulRunner";

            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(XulRunnerPath, "*.dll");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                LoadWin32Library(file);
            }
        }
```

what can cause this error. In win 7 works but when i copy to server i get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your error might be related to the fact that your server is x64 while your station is x32. Changing platform target in your .NET build to x32 from Any CPU might solve your problem. The correct solution would be though to compile freebl3.dll for x64.